# Replace/Hide Input Button If Form Is Validated (Using jquery.validate.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, submit

I have this normal form:

```
<form class="vform" action='http://example.com/someaction.php' method='post' id='myid' >
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="required email " placeholder="Enter Your Email" >
    <input id="#before" type='submit' value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am using the jquery.validate.js plugin to validate the form, which is working fine. ([Link](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js))

**WHAT IS REQUIRED:**
**Before** the user is redirected upon successful validation of the form, there is this 'pause' (while its redirecting)... during this time, users are repeatedly hitting the submit button.

How can I hide/replace (maybe with a loading gif or something) the submit button IF the form is validated.

Meaning, disable or replace the input button with something else **IF** the form is validated.

**THE VALIDATION CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".vform").validate();
    });
</script>
```

I tried adding some replacement/disable code after the validate function like this:

```
$(this).children('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

or

```
$('#before').replaceWith($('#after'));
```

But confused as to how to actually go about it.

Can anyone offer some insight?

EDIT: **The input button shouldn't be replaced/disabled if the form validation is false**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `submitHandler` of jQuery validate.

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".vform").validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) { // <- pass 'form' argument in
            $("#before").attr("disabled", true);
            form.submit(); // <- use 'form' argument here.
        }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Nishant, thanks for the fast response. I am trying your code, but on clicking the input button (successfully), it sort of "freezes" for a while (in the pressed state) and then the code is submitted. (Also, note: the entire fiddle page freezes! :S)

Please check this sample fiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/amodoke/2hgnZ/614/

Comment: @Amod i have edited my answer. Now it should work fine. Updated fiddle can be accessed at http://jsfiddle.net/2hgnZ/615/

Comment: @Amod If this answer solves your problem, please accept answer.